# byobu configuration menu escape / exit always closes the tab

Tags: osx, menu, homebrew, byobu

I've been using byobu for ~4 years at this point and I do not remember this behavior before. If I press F1 (this always happens by accident actually, with the exception of initial setup I never want to see this menu again) which brings up the byobu configuration menu the normal way to exit is to press the escape key. This used to bring me right back to the byobu tab I was on. But now, it closes the current tab, making me lose that tab. I can't tell if the session / programs are still running (haven't tested anything really).

How do I fix this behavior so it doesn't close? Is it a new bug / change in behavior? Or is there some potential odd thing in my setup that could be causing this?

I'm using a mac.

Comment: I've been trying to narrow this down myself and believe this behavior is being caused by **tmux**. If I run `byobu-screen`, bringing up the config and then exiting returns me to the byobu session. A you described, doing the same thing with `byobu-tmux` exits the calling shell of the `new-window` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following lines to the `~/.byobu/keybindings.tmux` file:

```
unbind-key -n F1
unbind-key -n F9
bind-key F1 new-window -n config byobu-config
bind-key F9 new-window -n config byobu-config
```

This removes a `-k` argument of the `new-window` command which kills the existing window and replaces it. I don't know if this issue affects other operating systems; I suspect this is a macOS X issue.

Comment: Tested and verified this works. Thank you.

Comment: It is not MacOS X only. Have the same on Fedora 30.

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/byobu/+bug/1813986